# Update data from query in table when select using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

My HTML code is very simple :

```
<body>

<form id="delForm" action="deleteThirdMulti.php" method="post"> <!--Le fomulaire qui ne sert que pour les checkbox-->
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-1 pull-right">
            <a href="addThird.php"><img src="CSS/PICTURES/add.png" /></a>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="delete_all">Supprimer</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
            <select name="choix_service" class="form-control form-update-user" id="sort">
                <option selected="selected">TOUS</option>
                <option value="COMPTABILITE">CLIENT</option>
                <option value="EXPLOITATION">AFFRETE</option>
                <option value="INFORMATIQUE">PROPRIETAIRE</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>        
    <table class="table table-condensed table-responsive table-bordered sortable table-striped" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this)" name="check_all"/></th>
                <th class="text-center">Type</th>
                <th class="text-center">Code</th>
                <th class="text-center">Nom</th>
                <th class="text-center">Adresse 1</th>
                <th class="text-center">Adresse 2</th>
                <th class="text-center">Code Postal</th>
                <th class="text-center">Ville</th>
                <th class="text-center">Pays</th>
                <th class="text-center">Téléphone</th>
                <th class="text-center">Fax</th>
                <th class="text-center">E-mail</th>
                <th class="text-center">Site web</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
```

And then, I have a PHP code which display datas from the database.

The problem is that I would like the user to be able to change the value in the select box and, I would like the datas to be updated without a page reload. Indeed, when I select CLIENT, only CLIENTS from the base will be displayed in the table.

My start of Jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sort').change(function(){
      var valeur = $('#sort option:selected').text();
      $.ajax({
        url: 'some-url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: valeur,
        success: function(data) {
                   ... do something with the data...
                 }
    });
  })
});

</script>
```

Comment: And what is the __real__ problem?

Comment: Show us the PHP code that is retrieving the data from the database. Then we may be able to see how you would deal with whatever data you are returning. _We are not clairvoyant_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your Success function on the Ajax call you will want to loop through the data and use jquery's

```
.html(text)
```

function to fill in the table data.

It may be easier to wrap the table `id="table"` inside a div container so you can write the entire table HTML from within your success function in the AJAX.

I hope this addresses your question, it was a little unclear what you are trying to accomplish, but it seems there is some language barriers here that we can hopefully overcome.

Let me know if you need any clarification on things!

---

Clarification for comment #1:

create a div on the page for your ajax response information.  Let's call this "clients_table_container"

```
<div id="clients_table_container"></div>
```

When your ajax response success function is called, you can fill the content of this container div with the html code you would like to display.  For Example:

```
success: function(data)
{
    //TODO: Turn JSON into html string content
    var my_html_string = data;

    //REPLACE THE CONTENT IN THE DIV WITH THIS DATA
    $('#clients_table_container').html(my_html_string);
}
```

You'll want to make sure you have the `<table>` html inside the `my_html_string` variable and you fill in the `<tr><td></td></tr>` tags based on the json response in the `data` variable.  This part you will have todo as we have no visibility into it's contents.

Comment: In fact, I can't imagine how it works... If I put a div for my table, so I will be able to put a new table built in my php file where AJAX is going, instead of the original one?

Comment: I have added an edit to my answer to hopefully explain the concept a little better.

Comment: I've been sucessfull :) Indeed, I didn't know the return of HTML values from AJAX. This is completely awesome ! Thank you so much for your clarification.

Comment: Glad I could help!!! And thank you for marking the answer accepted!  IF you want to use ajax from a  bundled function, take a look at this convenience script I wrote awhile ago:  http://pastebin.com/7nRrE2Jd  --- From there you can just call that function with the right arguments and be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

It works !

This is my code in the AJAX PHP file :

```
<?php

include('../sqlConnexion.php');

include('../security.php');

if ($_POST['valeur'] == 'TOUS')
{
    $req = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM tiers ORDER BY code');
    $response['i'] = $_POST['valeur'];
}
else
{
    $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM tiers WHERE type = :type ORDER BY code');
    $req->execute(array(
    'type' => $_POST['valeur']
));
}

$response['table'] = '';

$i = 0;    
while ($third=$req->fetch())
{
    $response['table'] = $response['table'] . "<tr>
    <td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='delete_$i' value='".$third['id']."'></td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['type'] . "</td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['code'] . "</td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['nom'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['adresse1'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['adresse2'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['cp'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['ville'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['pays'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['telephone'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['fax'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'>" . $third['email'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'><a target='blank_' href='" . $third['website'] . "'>" . $third['website'] . " </td>
    <td align='center'><a href='updateThird.php?id=" . $third['id'] . "'><img src='CSS/PICTURES/modification.jpg' title='Modifier le tiers'/></a></td>
    </tr>";
    $i++;
}

$req->closeCursor();

echo json_encode($response);
```

Here is my JQuery code with filling the 'tbody' :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sort').change(function(){
      var valeur = $('#sort option:selected').text();
      //window.location.replace('thirdManagement.php?third=' + valeur);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'MODEL/ajaxSearchThirds.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'valeur': valeur},
        success: function(data) {
                   $('tbody').html(data.table);
                   $('#ivalue').val(data.i);
        }
      });
  })
});
```

Hope it will help someone.